# How to retrieve the date from Easypick when it is selected?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to retrieve the selected dates from Easypicker but I can't do it even if I apply the methods in the documentation

```js
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 2);

const picker = new easepick.create({
    element: "#datepicker",
    css: [
        "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/bundle@1.2.1/dist/index.css"
    ],
    zIndex: 50,
    lang: "fr-FR",
    format: "DD MMM YYYY",
    header: "Dates de location",
    LockPlugin: {
        minDate: date,
        selectForward: true
    },
    plugins: [
        "RangePlugin",
        "LockPlugin"
    ],
    RangePlugin: {
        locale: {
          one: 'jour',
          other: 'jours',
        },
    },
    onClickCalendarDay: function () {
        console.log(picker.getEndDate())
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the method of picker object getStartDate and getEndDate.

Here is the Example:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 2);

const picker = new easepick.create({
  element: "#datepicker",
  css: [
    "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/bundle@1.2.1/dist/index.css"
  ],
  zIndex: 50,
  lang: "fr-FR",
  format: "DD MMM YYYY",
  header: "Dates de location",
  LockPlugin: {
    minDate: date,
    selectForward: true
  },
  plugins: ["RangePlugin", "LockPlugin"],
  RangePlugin: {
    locale: {
      one: 'jour',
      other: 'jours',
    },
  },
  onClickCalendarDay: function() {
    console.log(picker.getEndDate());
  }
});

// Retrieve selected dates
const startDate = picker.getStartDate();
const endDate = picker.getEndDate();

console.log(startDate);
console.log(endDate);
```